# How to read elements of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, serial-port

I am taking data from serial port using these commands:

```
char buf [256];
char a [256];
memset (&buf, '\0', sizeof buf);

/* *** READ *** */
if (n < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}

/* Print what I read... */
std::cout << "" << buf;
int sa=0;
printf("Gelen Data : \n");

for(sa=0;sa<15;sa++){
    printf("::%0.2X",buf[sa]);
}
```

and this is my data:

```
::02::03::98::00::07::20::16::09::29::16::19::45::C0::00::00::00
```

I can see data coming using these commands:

```
for(sa=0;sa<15;sa++){
        printf("::%0.2X",buf[sa]);
}
```

but I don't use elements of the `buf[]` array in any equation; for example, I want to use `buf[2]` in an equation like below:

```
if(buf[2]==02){
    cout<<"Equality"<<endl;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why can't you use the example code you posted? (I believe you're misusing the term "equation"; that's not an equation, and there are no equations in C++.)

Comment: Copy the text of the program to your question. No screenshots or pictures of text please.

Comment: I have turned the screenshot into a code block and fixed some wording. Also, the question is already tagged [tag:c++], no need to add that to the title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to compare them in hexadecimal format.

```
if( buf[2]==0x02){
      cout<<"Equality"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @MuhammedYıldız, please accept answers and upvote them as well if you think they solved your problem.

Comment: I upvoted but i think it will recorded after i reached 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Can also use a switch statement with hex values, which can have performance improvements, or more likely - if you've a lot of values to work with, make the code more readable.
ie

```
switch (buf[2]) {
  case 0x02:
    doSomething(); break;
  case 0x04: 
    soSomethingelse(); break;
}
```